# Weird Associative Array

Tags: php

At the moment I got very weird bug in PHP related with Associative Array, here the chunk of code:

```
$value="Hello World";
echo $value['randomassocname'];
```

Why it always return the first character which is "H" even though there's no assoc array attached ? how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug! If you have [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) on:

```
<?php
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

You would get this error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'randomassocname'

So because you have that off you don't see the error and `randomassocname` gets implicit casted to an integer here `0` and it access the first character of the string